# Insufficient Privileges error on record detail in Partner Community

Tags: sharing, community, roles, public-group, queue

I've got Partner Community Users (*not* High Volume) and I want them to see a Contract record. I recognize there is no `ContractShare` and his visibility must be absorbed from the `Account`

The Sharing Settings for the org appear in order, and `External Sharing` is disabled.

So I've tried all of the following:

- created a Permission Set with *View* on `Contract`
- enabled the Profile with *View* on `Contract`
- added an `AccountShare` with the `User`
- shared the `Account` with the `Role`
- created a `Group` and shared that too,

But every time I view the damn Contract, it barfs **Insufficient Privileges**.

What else, any ideas!?

Comment: I just tested it with OWD public rw and I was able to view a contract with a partner user. Is your user the owner? If not how does he relate in the roles hierarchy? Is your OWD set to private?

Comment: @UweHeim yes, `Account` OWD is set to `Private`

Comment: And how you shared the Account with the partner user? Via role hierarchy or via manual sharing or differently? Or is he Owner himself?

Comment: I see, it's in your question. Using manual sharing, it seems to work. So I can't reproduce it. My guess is via Role it'll work, too.

Comment: Is the partner user able to view the account? I mean really the account and not the associated contract?

Comment: @UweHeim He is not the owner, but I've tried manually sharing through the GUI, inserting the share in Apex API, and every combination in between with `User`, `Group` and `Role` all to no avail with `Contract` or `Account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it now, bit of a curveball!

I noticed that, while the detail view was barfing **Insufficient Privileges**, the darn records *were* in fact appearing in ListViews and searches! So I'd believe the row-level sharing is working just fine.

On both `Account` and `Contract` there was a **Visualforce Page override** on *View* which was exacerbated by the fact *Communities do not redirect to /apex/... when serving override pages*.

So I went to the setup menus to find the names of the respective Visualforce Pages:

- Setup > Customize > Accounts > Buttons, Links and Actions,
- Setup > Customize > Contracts > Buttons, Links and Actions,

and added those guys to the Permission Set used by the Partner Community User, then it worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tested it in a community and it seems that contracts a viewable for partner users with the settings: OWD=private, partner is not owner, shared manually. I pretty much stripped all other privileges. So at there seems not to be a general limit. Has to be something very specific.

Just a list on what I would test to drill down the issue:

- Record-Type availability? Do you have more than one record type?
- Can partner user view the associated account?
- Can partner user view the contract when owned by himself? If not: Profile, otherwise Role/Sharing
- Try to create a new profile (copy form standard partner) and a new user

[image]

Here is the profile:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks indeed for your detailed diagnosis and exploration!